# Xcode5/iOS7 Localizable Splash and app icon

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm building an app that supports 3 languages.

It's necessary to have the app name, the app icon and the splash screen in the language that the phone is using.

In this moment i can do this with the app name, but i don't have been succeeded in the other features (app icon and splash).

Can anyone help me?

Regards

**EDIT**

Thanks for all your answers :)

To solve this i have localized the splash screens images (to the languages i want) and it works.

To the app icon does not have the same success. I still try fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at Apple documentation?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001119-105003

EDIT:
All you have to do is creating a folder for each language.

english = 'en.lproj'

french =  'fn.lproj'

Spanish = 'es.lproj'

and so on.
Those 'lproj' folders you need to put in your bundle, and put the appropriate resources in each folder.

Comment: Consider updating your answer with a brief summary of the salient points. That way it will remain useful to others, even if the link changes or breaks.

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: This is probably the only answer worth giving, but it indeed should be a comment (and the question closed if it is extremely trivial to find out)